# How to replace contentdrawer in appdrawer with an appcompact activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I know how to do that using fragments using the code bellow:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment myFragment= new custProductFrag();
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;

    if (id == R.id.nav_products) {
        myFragment=new custProductFrag();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_shipment) {
        myFragment=new custShipmentFrag();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_report) {
        myFragment=new custReportFrag();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_acc) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        logout();
    }

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.contentStuff,myFragment)
            .commit();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

But i want custProduct for example to extend AppCompatActivity.

UPDATE:
I don't know if this is safe but it's working for me now using Linear Inflater
but had to add ID child for each child layout out there:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentStuff);

    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;

    if (id == R.id.nav_products) {
        LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child);
        container.removeView(child);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_products, container);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_shipment) {
        LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child);
        container.removeView(child);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_shipment, container);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_report) {

        LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child);
        container.removeView(child);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_report, container);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_acc) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        logout();
    }
```